# Write an object of the class "coeftest" on a text file in R

Tags: r, extract

Here is an object of the class `coeftest`

```
m = lm(data=mtcars, cyl ~ disp * wt * hp)
coef = coeftest(m, vcov=sandwich(m))

t test of coefficients:

               Estimate  Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  8.0462e+00  1.4281e+00  5.6342 8.431e-06 ***
disp        -3.9661e-03  1.7331e-02 -0.2288  0.820929    
wt          -2.8621e+00  5.2758e-01 -5.4250 1.423e-05 ***
hp          -4.5629e-02  9.5038e-03 -4.8011 6.887e-05 ***
disp:wt      9.6036e-03  4.5263e-03  2.1218  0.044377 *  
disp:hp      1.1880e-04  7.8606e-05  1.5114  0.143742    
wt:hp        2.5839e-02  3.6615e-03  7.0569 2.697e-07 ***
disp:wt:hp  -7.2312e-05  2.0855e-05 -3.4674  0.001997 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I'd like to extract either the whole object or only the matrix (with the stars) inside it. I tried with `write`, `write.table`, `writeLines` and `cat` but none of them worked.

The only solution I found is this one:

```
coef = coef[1:nrow(coef), 1:ncol(coef)]
cat(file=path, x=coef, append=T, quote=F)
```

But doing so eliminates the stars (significant codes).

Comment: R core has given serious consideration to eliminating the "stars" entirely. The stars are seen by real statisticians as a combination of crutch and trap for persons with a constricted view of statistics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you want, but here are two options to consider. We start with this:

```
library(lmtest)
library(sandwich)
m <- lm(data=mtcars, cyl ~ disp * wt * hp)
coef <- coeftest(m, vcov=sandwich(m))
```

#### Option 1: `capture.output`

This matches what is asked for in your title, and it is *very* straightforward. The following will create a file named "test.txt" that has the output of `coef` in it.

```
capture.output(coef, file="test.txt")
```

#### Option 2: `write.csv` after some tweaking

The stars aren't actually part of the data, but are taken care of the print method. (See the code for `printCoefmat` for details). But, we can create a vector of those stars, and `cbind` that to the output, and write that to a CSV file.

```
stars <- symnum(coef[, ncol(coef)], corr = FALSE, na = FALSE, 
                cutpoints = c(0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1), 
                symbols = c("***", "**", "*", ".", " "))

out <- cbind(as.data.frame.matrix(coef), Stars = format(stars))
write.csv(out, "test.csv")
```

Comment: Just to add, if you want the output to display the same way 
```paste(capture.output(coef), collapse = "\n")```